# Makefile with two targets with the same name

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile containing an include statement. I have no control over the content of the included makefile. Still, I want to be able to add some pre-processing steps before "some" (not all) of the targets. Consider the following example:

```
install:
      @echo "install target"

include othermakefile.mk
```

*othermakefile.mk* contains *install* target as well. If I run this script, make gives a warning and ignores the first *install* target.

Comment: Then rename your targets to something that is very unlikely to clash (`foo_blah_install` for instance).

Comment: As I said, I want the script to run some **preprocessing** commands when the user enters "make install". I don't want to change the name of the target.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1644920/86967

Answer (score 3):

Nothing easier:

```
install: pre_install

.PHONY: pre_install
pre_install:
    do preinstallation things

include othermakefile.mk
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to run `pre_install` before `install` *or any of its preqs*, here is a way. It's crude and ugly, but it does the job:

```
install: pre_install
    $(MAKE) -f othermakefile.mk $@

.PHONY: pre_install
pre_install:
    do preinstallation things
```

Note that this will not necessarily rebuild all prerequisites of `install`, so some of them may remain in their old states and not reflect the effects of `pre_install`. If that's not good enough, and you want `pre_install` before *all* of the other prerequisites, you can add an option flag:

```
install: pre_install
    $(MAKE) --always-make -f othermakefile.mk $@
```

Now Make will assume that all targets are out of date, and rebuild from the ground up (after `pre_install`).

Comment: +1.  But is it guaranteed that Make will process `install`s dependencies in top-to-bottom order?  i.e. If `othermakefile.mk` contains `install: foobar`, is it guaranteed that `pre_install` gets processed before `foorbar`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: no, there's no such guarantee; Make will build `pre_install` before `install` (which is how I read the question), but not necessarily before `install`'s other prerequisites. There *is* a way to put it ahead of all other targets, but it's more drastic.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can *put it ahead of all other prerequisites*?