# Two targets with the same name in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I was wondering what happens if there is 2 targets with the same name in a Makefile:

According to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125057/makefile-with-two-targets-with-the-same-name), Having 2 targets with the same name throws warnings.

However, i don't understand how this Makefile in openwrt works:

In `include/package.mk`:

```
define Build/DefaultTargets
$(if $(QUILT),$(Build/Quilt))
$(if $(USE_SOURCE_DIR)$(USE_GIT_TREE),,$(if $(strip $(PKG_SOURCE_URL)),$(call Download,default)))
$(call Build/Autoclean)

download:
    $(foreach hook,$(Hooks/Download),
    $(call $(hook))$(sep)
)
```

Note here the call to `Download`function in the 3rd line and the definition of the target `download` in the 6th line.

By having a look at the definition of the function `Download` in `include/download.mk`:

```
define Download
  $(eval $(Download/Defaults))
  $(eval $(Download/$(1)))
  $(foreach FIELD,URL FILE $(Validate/$(call dl_method,$(URL),$(PROTO))),
  ifeq ($($(FIELD)),)
    $$(error Download/$(1) is missing the $(FIELD) field.)
  endif
)

$(foreach dep,$(DOWNLOAD_RDEP),
$(dep): $(DL_DIR)/$(FILE)
)
download: $(DL_DIR)/$(FILE)
```

I see that the `download` target is redefined.
What i know is that using `call` will expand the function, so how this could work?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html#Multiple-Rules

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a target is specified without a recipe, it's simply adding a dependency to the target.   You're allowed as many of these as you want.   So the following is valid:

```
foo: dep1 dep2

foo: dep3
    recipe1
```

In which case, if dep1, dep2, or dep3 are rebuilt, then recipe1 is run.  But this is not:

```
foo:
    recipe1

foo:
    recipe2
```

At this point make wouldn't know which recipe to run, and/or in which order, so Make complains.  (note that you can have multiple definitions for [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html), in which case make chooses the first one that matches, but that's not allowed with static rules)