# Instead of "overriding commands for target", extend them

Tags: makefile

In my current setting, I have some `.mk` that are automatically generated, over which I have no control. One of the rules defined in these files is `clean`.

The part of the code I am working on uses `include` to access variables from those `.mk` files. However, I'd like to have another rule `clean` to remove the files generated in the folder I am working on.

If I create a rule named `clean`, I get the warning

```
warning: overriding commands for target
```

Is there a way to "extend" clean, i.e., o make it run both the `clean` defined in those `.mk` files and my own `clean`?

Of course, [I could create another rule `other_clean` and call the old `clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644920/override-target-in-makefile-to-add-more-commands). Or also I could do something like:

```
other_clean:
    make clean
    rm *.o
```

But I'd like to know if there is any functionality in make that allows me to "inherit" the recipe defined elsewhere into my own `clean`. I saw there are these things called [double-colon rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html#Double_002dColon), but I can't use them because the files I am including are automatically generated.

Comment: You've already discovered double colon rules but if you can't change the file then that's moot, just define a different name (remember to make it `.PHONY`), and have it depend on `clean`, i.e `other_clean: clean`.

Comment: Actually... the question was more out of curiosity, to know if there was anything that I was missing that did the job exactly in the way I wanted (i.e., using the name "clean"). After all, it feels more elegant to remember "clean" than to remember any other name that I may, in the far future, forget.

Comment: There is one other way but it still involves changing the original recipe: say the `clean` recipe is defined as `clean: ; rm whatever.foo`, if you change this to `clean: ; rm $(stuff_to_clean)` you can then provide target-specific variable overrides later on such as `clean: stuff_to_clean += some_other_file.foo`, as long as only a single definition of the `clean` rule contains recipes this is fine.

Comment: I think you should investigate the double-colon rule: http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makecolon.html